# Capacitor/Ionic: Handling push notification in background or when app was killed

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic-native, capacitor

Goodmorning everyone,
I haven't been able to find a solution for several hours now.

I use the "PushNotifications" Capacitor plugin (https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/push-notifications/) to listen to push notifications that come to me from firebase (both notification and data type), the listening of notifications happens very well and everything behaves as expected even in cases of app killed or in the background.

The problem is the following:

I want to open the app when I receive a notification, if it is in the background or if it has been killed.

1. In the case of notification received when the app is in the **foreground**, I can run custom code using
   `addListener(eventName: "pushNotificationReceived", callback)`
   and in any case I have no problems because the app is open.
2. In case of notification received when the app is in the **background**, I can force the app to keep the backgroundMode active (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode)
   and bring the app to the foreground upon receiving a notification. (although I don't really like it because it's battery consuming)
3. In case of app **killed**, I have not found solutions to the problem.

It seems that there is no way to hook custom code to be able to run when a push notification arrives when it is received in the background or with the app killed, have you ever had this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Any news about it ? I try to disable battery optimization on my mobile device for my Ionic Capacitor app. Then, I was able to receive push notif when app was killed. I even try to enable again the optimisation and surprise, push notif works too. Seems strange. Hope that's not the final solution.

Comment: How did you get to have notifications in foreground in Android? https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/2261 
This says foreground notification is not available for Android, only in iOS
To get them we have to use Local Notifications... Could you explain how you did?

Comment: Sorry to hijack a little and I appreciate that I'm late on this but were you able to perform a router.navigateByUrl() within your pushNotificationReceived listener? I am seeing the navigation be triggered without any change on screen and wondered if this was something which needed a workaround? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

My solution was to add: **FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY** action to **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
        <activity
        ...
        android:name="com.appname.MainActivity"
        ...>

        ...
        ...
        ...

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In addition on the server you should include the action in your push notification object:

```
  const pushNotification = {
  data: {
    ...
  },
  notification: {
    body: body,
    title: title,
    click_action: 'FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY',
  },
};
```

And inside you ionic project you handle **pushNotificationActionPerformed** like below and navigate to the desired route:

```
  PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationActionPerformed',
  (notification: PushNotificationActionPerformed) => {
    console.log('Push action performed: ' + JSON.stringify(notification));
  }
);
```

To handle receiving push notifications in when the app is open you should handle **pushNotificationReceived** and show a toast yourself if needed.

```
// the app is open, show your own notification if needed
PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationReceived',
  (notification: PushNotification) => {
    console.log('push notification received: ' + JSON.stringify(notification));
  }
);
```

Comment: Do you receive notifications in foreground for Android? With that implementation?

Comment: you receive them but you have to show them manually, check updated answer.

Comment: click_action doesm't seem to be a valid input inside "notification" with the v1 api https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#Notification

Comment: @Kevin https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#androidnotification

Comment: Correct, that's inside the "android" section, not "notification" (though android of course has its own notification)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it with the following lines in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="yourapp_notifications_channel_name" />
<service android:name="com.getcapacitor.CapacitorFirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="false">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
</intent-filter>
</service>
```

Change "yourapp_notifications_channel_name" with a name as you want but you have to add it to your capacitor PushNotification as the following:

````
if (this.platform.is('android')) {
  const channel: Channel = {
     id: 'yourapp_notifications_channel',
     name: 'yourapp_notifications_channel',
     sound: 'yourapp_notification_sound_file_name',
     importance: 5,
     visibility: 1,
     vibration: true
   };
   await PushNotifications.createChannel(channel);
}
PushNotifications.addListener('registration', async (fcmToken: Token) => {
/// your notificaiton logic
}```
````

Comment: Is this still working for you @Nour Krimesh?

Comment: this works like a charm. The main issue is that while using FCM you might not be giving channel name.

Comment: Is this answer for Capacitor 2, 3 or 4?

Answer (score 0):

For us background-notifications (even after App was killed) also worked if we additionally installed the FCM Plugin (https://github.com/capacitor-community/fcm), which we need for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. It was a technical underpinning of how messages are sent. Here is a PHP function that sends notifications from the server to the device. "data" is message sent to app, "notification" is sent to android OS.

```
function sendGCM($message, $id) {


    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $fields = array (
            'registration_ids' => array (
                    $id // The device token
            ),
            'data' => array (
                    "message" => $message
            ),
            // After I put "notification", the device started to receive notifications in the background:
            'notification' => array (
                "title" => "App Title Notification",
                "body" => $message
            )
    );
    $fields = json_encode ( $fields );

    $headers = array (
            'Authorization: key=' . "MY_API_Cloud_Messaging_KEY", // App Key from console.firebase.google.com
            'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

    $result = curl_exec ( $ch );
    echo $result;
    curl_close ( $ch );

}
```