# Modify push notifications using capacitor plugin

Tags: push-notification, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

Is it possible to modify incoming push messages using @capacitor/push-notifications? I‘m sending messages using Firebase Cloud Messaging to my Android and iOS apps, which are encrypted by my backend and should be decrypted by the app. To achieve this, I must modify the messages shown in the notification centers after receiving them.

I didn‘t find any documentation on this, so I would appreciate any hint into achieving this. If this is not supported, is there any other solution I could use?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62533419/capacitor-ionic-handling-push-notification-in-background-or-when-app-was-killed

Comment: Check [this Question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62533419/capacitor-ionic-handling-push-notification-in-background-or-when-app-was-killed)

Answer (score 1):

You can send a data notification (which is not automatically displayed by Android) and then use `@capacitor/local-notifications` to show the modified notification.

Comment: And what about iOS? In the docs, it says it doesn't support silent/data notifications. https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/push-notifications#silent-push-notifications-data-only-notifications

Comment: You can use another plugin which supports silent notifications on iOS (e.g. [`@capacitor-firebase/messaging`](https://github.com/robingenz/capacitor-firebase)).